# Show selection menu after inserting element in tags+autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I have a tags list with autocomplete.
But the list with suggestion does not show after you insert an element.
(you need to start typing, hit space, down-arrow ... and this is not intuitive for **our users** )

Is there a way to make the dropdown list to show after adding an element?

I tried with the property `on-tag-added` but not sure what function to use.

```
<tags-input
        ng-model="recipe.categories"
        display-property="name"
        add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
        placeholder="Add Category"
        add-on-blur="true"
        on-tag-added="test('Open Sesame')"
    >
        <auto-complete
            source="loadTags($query)"
            min-length="0"
            max-results-to-show="64"
            load-on-focus="true"
            load-on-empty="true"
            load-on-click="true"
            load-on-down-arrow="true">
        </auto-complete>

    </tags-input>
```

**ng-tags-input** source:
https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput

Comment: I just tested what you pasted here and it really works. After add an element it automatically suggests another, take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/bRVpRs9Miq16PEw6qcJY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! it seems it works properly on the latest version of the library